# How can I dynamically create a Route in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm having trouble finding information on this subject because I don't know exactly what to search for and could use some direction on where I could find more information.

Let's say I have a `/blog` page where I'm able to create a blog. I click a button that opens a form and I fill out all the information: title of blog, blog message, today's date, etc. After that I submit the post (*let's call it First Blog*) and I get redirected back to the same `/blog` page. Now I'm able to click the title of my First Blog post and it redirects me to a new page. Example: `/blog/id=0001`.

I'm obviously not going to have to manually create a brand new Component each time I make a new post so React must have some way to dynamically create pages and automatically display stored information but I'm having trouble finding sources on how I can implement those features and more importantly what would be the best way to display that information in a new page? I'm assuming I would need to store everything in an array and make it display things based on an `id`.

Comment: React don’t “dynamically create pages”; you’d use a router that allows URL parameters and use the parameter to fetch the article. The specifics would depend on how you’re doing routing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup you could use `useParams` for that, https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params

```
import { Routes, Route, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProfilePage() {
  // Get the userId param from the URL.
  let { userId } = useParams();
  // ...
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="users">
        <Route path=":userId" element={<ProfilePage />} />
        <Route path="me" element={...} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

with `:userId`, you could think of it as a wild card. For example, if you redirect the user to `/users/123`, you ccan get `useParams()` to get the `userId` and get 123 as a result, which you could use it to fetch to DB or something else.

This method is called route parameters.